# return a list of string as JSONResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

how would I return a list of string in a json result in C# asp.net MVC?

I have this controller

```
  public JsonResult AutoCompletePart(string id)
    {
        AutoCompleteService srv = new AutoCompleteService();
        string[] parts = srv.AutoCompleteItemMaster(id);

        //how do i return parts as JSON?

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: That's an array, not a `List<String>`.

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you returning to?

Comment: i was using jquery UI autocomplete. But I don't like how it looks and it was way slow. so i am looking for another one. know of a better one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
return Json(parts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will return a simple Javascript string array.
If you want to return  specific format, please provide more detail.

Comment: I love how easy this is in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: NICE! I was making it harder than it was! Thanks!